# Python: Exception handling

Tags: python, file, tkinter, exception

The code below asks the user to input a directory and a word. The program searches for the word through files in the directory and sub subdirectories. It prints out the name of the directories, how many directories and files that has bee searched in and the number of times the word is found. The code seem to work, but I would like it to print "Folder not found" if the user type in a path that does not exist. The attempt below prints nothing. Any ideas?

```
import os
import tkinter as tk

results = []
dirs = 0  
files = 0
words = 0

def recSearch(path,word):
    global dirs
    global files
    global words
    foldername = os.listdir(path)  
    
    try:
        for i in foldername:
            if os.path.isdir(f"{path}\\{i}"): 
                results.append(f"{path}\\{i}") 
                dirs += 1 
                recSearch((f"{path}\\{i}"),word) 
            else: 
                with open(os.path.join(path, i), "r") as fileObject:
                    for j in fileObject: 
                        if word in j:
                            files += 1
                            words += j.count(word) 
    except NotFound:
        text.insert('end', 'Folder not found')

def click():
    recSearch(path.get(), word.get()) 
    text.insert('end', "Search start\n---------------------------------\n")   
    for i in results:
        text.insert('end', i + "\n")
    text.insert('end', '---------------------------------\n')
    text.insert('end', f"Searched: {dirs} directories and {files} files, found {words} occurences of {word.get()}")

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Find word")
path = tk.StringVar()
entry = tk.Entry(window, textvariable=path, width=50)
entry.insert(-1,"Directory or filename")
word = tk.StringVar()
word_entry = tk.Entry(window, textvariable=word, width=20)
word_entry.insert(-1, "Word")
search_button = tk.Button(window, text="Search", width=15, command=click)      
text = tk.Text(window, height=50, width=180)
entry.grid(row=0, column=0)
word_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)
search_button.grid(row=0, column=2)
text.grid(row=1, columnspan=3)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Where is `NotFound` defined? Also, you probably want less code in the `try` block. Put it *inside* the loop, ideally around only the line that would raise `NotFound` in the first place.

Comment: You need to put `foldername = os.listdir(path)` inside `try` and catch `FileNotFoundError` instead of `NotFound` (I think it is not defined).